# Google Search console: We had a problem submitting your indexing request. Please try again later

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I recently published my website live, everything seems to be okay except for adding  URL'S in the inspector with index request. Live testing is not an issue.

The website is now 5 days on air, I removed the no-index and maintenance correctly. Also robots.txt is fine and reachable.

It seems when I am able to click the index button, it looks like there is a loop. And sometimes I get the error

> "We had a problem submitting your indexing request. Please try again
> later."

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that  `We had a problem submitting your indexing request. Please try again later` means that

- Either there was a temporary hiccup with Google
- Or there is a problem with your pages

I would suspect the latter.  Consider trying web site checkers, there are many out there.  I use [ahrefs](https://ahrefs.com/) in the free mode.  (I am not associated with it).

Note for new websites, full indexing can easily take six months.  And it is vital to eliminate all errors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the sitemap you've already submitted and then re-submit it. Check back after a few hours, at least after a day, and you'll see the problem is resolved. In my case, I did the same and now I'm able to perform Request Indexing successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You mention removing the "no index...correctly".  I recently experienced a similar message when submitting URLS to Google and the "no index" was still enabled for a page I submitted.  Google reminded me that the page couldn't be crawled due to the no-index in my robots.txt.  However, after removing the tag Google took several hours to recognize the no-index was gone.

After doing some research, I found mention of Google caching requests for inspection results for 24 hours [Crawl blocked by robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/4420484/crawl-blocked-by-robots-txt-while-it-s-not?hl=en).  After about 4-6 hours, Google error went away when requesting the page to be inspected.